# RailsのDeviseでsign_up時に認証メールのエラーが発生する。Net::SMTPSyntaxError - 501 Sender syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RailsアプリのDeviseで、confirmableモジュールを使用して認証メールを送信したいのですが、
Submitボタンを押下後、以下のエラーが発生してメールを送信することができません。

エラー分
Net::SMTPSyntaxError - 501 Sender syntax error

原因は何が考えられるでしょうか？
文法エラーなのは分かるのですが、どのファイルに問題があるのかわからずに困っております。何卒よろしくお願い致します。

```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Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3721ms (ActiveRecord: 25.8ms)



Net::SMTPSyntaxError - 501 Sender syntax error
```

#### ※以下から追記

ありがとうございます！ ご指摘の通りでした。

### #config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.mailer_sender = 'hogehoge/fugafuga株式会社'
end
```

になっていたところを、

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'hoge@gmail.com'
end
```

に変更したらエラーが解決しました。
アドバイスいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

送信者のメールアドレスの書式が不正なのではないでしょうか